# MS Access Freeze when opening file

Tags: microsoft-access

It might be something simple, but I can't find anything on the web yet...

When I try to open a file on MsAccess it just freezes completely. No error given or anything.

It started with the runtime for 2007, it's an mde what I wanna open

But then I tried opening one of the example dbs con Access 2019 (same pc) and that freezes too... Not only with the mde but also with the example databases/templates

Any idea what could it be?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the either the startup form (or autoexec macro if an older database) has some kind of error that is crashing but suppressing error message or maybe even screen repainting.

Before you open the database, hold the shift key down the entire time it is opening. Then press <kbd>F11</kbd> and hopefully you are at the database container window. Also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to get to the debug window and type this and press enter:

```
application.echo true
```

If you now see a form suddenly appear, then perhaps the startup code contains

```
application.echo false
```

but crashed before it executed the line resetting it back to true.

However since you are dealing with an `.mde` you might have limited introspection into the database objects (beyond the tables and queries). You might be able to export some of the objects to a new (non-locked) `.mdb` database (perhaps all of them). Also, encrypted `.mde` are usually crackable (if you want to get at all the source code).

But the later versions of access .accde was only crackable by one service in the UK (that I know of) plus you first have to prove to them you have the rights to crack open the source code.

P.S.  one last idea...

- uninstall the 2007 runtime   (which is the first of the .accdb .accde era)
- try it with the 2003 runtime  (which is the last of the .mdb .mde era)